# "By the next year, I will have been losing my dad for 5 years." "By the next year, I will have been working in this company for 5 years."

Tags: sentence-choice

I’m wondering if this sentence is grammatically correct or not!

> By the next year, I will have been losing my dad for 5 years.
>
> By the next year, I will have been working in this company for 5 years.

Comment: Why do you wonder this? what is specifically difficult or unclear for you? Do you think both sentences are equally correct? Do you think there is a problem and if not what makes you doubt them?

Comment: Generally we lose our fathers just once, not over a period of time.

Comment: There are two major errors. **1.** “By next year...” probably just means “Next year...”. **2.** Unless your dad is gradually passing away, you probably mean, “...I will have been without my dad for five years.” (It’s been five years since he passed away.).